# ReactJS Unable to update prop through reducers

Tags: reactjs

I had created an app which shows customer details as a list with two buttons Edit/Delete. But when I click delete button my reducer I see the customer list is empty.
My Reducer JS File

```
let customerReducer = function(customers = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_CUSTOMER':
        return [{
            name:action.name,
            address:action.address,
            id:0
          }, ...customers]
        case 'DELETE_CUSTOMER':
            {
                return customers.filter((customer) => {
                    return customer.id !== action.id
                })
            }
        default:
            return customers;
    }
}

export default customerReducer
```

When I print customers in Delete_Customer case I see it as empty array.
As I do not know where exactly I missed the link for customers props/state to reducers I have included my project URL to
Please find my project in github
[URL](https://github.com/yvsivateja/ReactJSApplications/tree/master/React-Simple-App)

**UPDATE:**

In my Client.js file if I initiate my props and in my APP.js if I access through props instead of state it is working fine.

```
let initialState ={
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Client 1",
      "address": "WaterStree,Zambia,LO"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Client ABC",
      "address": "ABC Street Hyderabad India 50050"
    }]
}
```

But I do not want to initiate instead would like to load through server call inside my component. In such scenario I need to access the result through state which wont update if I change the props

Comment: Yes, But here I would like to access the prevState and prepare a new one... Instead i'm having an empty resultset..

Comment: Each time you are calling the `customerReducer()` function you are creating a new empty array. Should you not be passing a prepopulated array and then add remove to that?

Comment: I believe that is just an initiation not the parameter/state that is being passed

Comment: @Pathfinder But here you are directly manipulating your redux state array. You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @Jackson That's not the problem. It will be initialized with empty array for the first time only. It's default value when the state value is not available when initializing.

Comment: @HardikModha even though I tried to mutate the state... I'm still getting an empty array there :(

Comment: @Pathfinder Have you first try logging/printing your state value inside `DELETE_CUSTOMER` case?? What value you are getting??

Comment: @HardikModha State in the sense?? my action props right??

Comment: @Pathfinder You have hard coded, `id` value when adding customer details. Is that a typo or ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137955/discussion-between-pathfinder-and-hardik-modha).

Comment: @HardikModha Where's he mutating state? Case `ADD_CUSTOMER` and `DELETE_CUSTOMER` both return new arrays - not a mutation of the old object.

Comment: @lux So where am I missing :(

Comment: @Pathfinder First, dispatch an `ADD_CUSTOMER` action to populate your customers state object. Then dispatch a `DELETE_CUSTOMER` action and put a breakpoint on the `return` statement -- is `customers` populated with the customer you added in `ADD_CUSTOMER`? If not, stop and troubleshoot that. If yes, is the returned array empty because you are in fact filtering out the customer?

Comment: @lux My bad. I misunderstood. Filter method returns a new array. So state will not be mutated.

Comment: @lux I pointed out a possible solution. OP is incorrectly accessing value when storing in state. He is accessing value as `action.name` whereas he should be accessing it as `action.customer.name`.

Comment: @lux when I add a cutomer I see in next state the new customer is populated... But in the browser displayed List i still see the old results.. i.e., my state is not updated

Comment: @HardikModha Good point. He'll need to validate his object shape.

Comment: @Pathfinder Sounds like your reducer _is_ working, but your components are not updating with the updated props. Are you using `connect()` with `react-redux` - that might be a completely different problem.

Comment: @lux yes using connect in App.js my parent component

Comment: @Pathfinder Cool. Put a breakdown in `mapStateToProps` in App.js and that should get hit after you dispatch your `ADD_CUSTOM`. Should be able to see if your new state is actually getting passed to your App.js. You may just be missing a `componentWillRecieveProps` allows the update to pass down.

Comment: @lux I do see my new customer when I add in this way "Object {customers: Array[1]}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137957/discussion-between-pathfinder-and-lux).

Comment: Please find the update to my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done everything right, but you forgot to use the customers from the state. In the component `App` in [App.js](https://github.com/yvsivateja/ReactJSApplications/blob/master/React-Simple-App/components/App.js) *you pass an empty array* as customers to the `CustomersView`:

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <span>
                <SideMenu headerText="React JS Application"/>
                <CustomersView customers={[]} actions={this.props.actions}/>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

Just use the customers from the state:

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <span>
                <SideMenu headerText="React JS Application"/>
                <CustomersView customers={this.props.customers} actions={this.props.actions}/>
            </span>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    const { customers } = state

    return { customers }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Ok. How do you build your code? (I tried running your project, but there was no npm-command for building the code, only for serving.)

Comment: I just use node server\server.js from the root folder and use http://localhost:3000/home to access it